# Checking prerequisite before installing eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, p2, update-site

I have eclipse feature and update site. I want to add prerequisites like

The plug-in can be installed, if the eclipse version greater than some version.

Can we compute these kind prerequisites before installing plug-in

Comment: P2 is computing these pre-requisites before an actual installation. What do you want to do with these?

Comment: @PeterKirschner: I want to check that my plug-in gets installed only after eclipse 4.4.

Comment: Then you should create a dependency to the corresponding Eclipse Feature including the version.

Comment: @PeterKirschner: Thanks. Is it possible to show an error message while installing, stating that you are using wrong version of eclipse, the supported version is 4.4 onwards...

Comment: P2 will automatically show such a error message when you try to install incompatible things.

Comment: @PeterKirschner: Is it possible to show some customized message?

Comment: Not as far as I know.